# Is there a workaround for PHP's inability to use a function return value in write context?

Tags: php

**I left my original question as is but wanted to point out the supposition of my question is flawed. Read the update for more**

---

I was surprised to discover that this does not work in PHP:

```
$someObjects = array();

function getInstance( $key )
{
    if ( ! $someObjects[$key] )
       $someObjects[$key] = new Object;

    return $someObjects[$key];
}

getInstance( 'mykey' )->property = 33;
```

The final line creates a fatal error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Can't use function return value in write context
```

It's a pattern that I've occasionally used in Actionscript that comes in handy when you need to define a bunch of objects explicitly (say in a config file) and you want to skip the instantiation step but also don't want to deal with the clutter of a bunch of nested arrays.

Any suggestions?

---

**Update**

This is one of those *duh* moments after reading the responses. My question wrongly supposes that `getInstance( 'mykey' )->property = 33` is the root cause of the fatal error.

My example code was sloppy, and had two big problems (ooops):

1. did not declare the `global` in the function body
2. incorrectly used `! $array[$key]` instead of `empty($array[$key])`

These problems were also in my project code but they do not appear to be the sole reason for the fatal error and I have since changed the project code and now I can't figure out what the other factor(s) are (?). At any rate, I got straightened out.

After the suggestions below this is the syntax I was aiming for:

```
class MetaInfo
{
    public $title;
    public $description;
}

/**
 * @param $key string
 * @return MetaInfo
 */
function getMeta( $key )
{
    global $meta;

    if ( empty($meta[$key]) )
        $meta[$key] = new MetaInfo;

    return $meta[$key];
}

getMeta( 'path/to/page' )->title = "Double-check your work before posting";
```

Comment: After your update, you can see from [this example](http://3v4l.org/sZubA) that this still works in PHP > 5.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is supported in PHP [5.0.0](http://3v4l.org/N2jKA) although I don't know how you got that to work. `$someObjects` wont be available in the scope of `getInstance()`. Here is what I tested with and it works:

```
<?php
class Object
{
    public $property;
}

function getInstance( $key )
{
    static $someObjects;
    if ( ! $someObjects[$key] )
       $someObjects[$key] = new Object;

    return $someObjects[$key];
}

echo getInstance( 'mykey' )->property = 33;  // prints 33 as expected
```

Comment: You should use `static $someObjects` instead of `global`.

Comment: You can see in [this example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/UshEOP) that it still works, plus you remove the global dependency.

Comment: Fixed, thank you. `static` didn't come to mind, glad you suggested it. :)

Comment: My situation is a little weird, but it is in fact the global context that I'm aiming at. Thanks for the examples vanneto and @nickb

Comment: Well, you can still use `global` for that. In any case, the real problem was the PHP version. You need [PHP version > 5.0.0](http://3v4l.org/N2jKA) for it to work.

Comment: I was using 5.3 and the error was "PHP Fatal error:  Can't use function return value in write context" so it was probably not a version issue but more an issue of bad syntax.\